# Get data from RethinkDB

Tags: model, dart, rethinkdb

In book "Dart Scalable Application Development" there are example to use  RethinkDB

```
  class UserStore{
      final List<User> users = new List();
      User user;
      Rethinkdb rdb = new Rethinkdb();
      Connection conn;

  // opening a connection to the database:
  openAndStore() {
    rdb.connect(db: "test", port:9090, host: "127.0.0.1").
    then((_conn) {
      conn = _conn;
      storeData(conn);
    }).catchError(print);
  }



  storeData(conn) {
    List jobsMap = new List();
    for (user in users) {
      var jobMap = user.toMap();
      jobsMap.add(jobMap);
    }
// storing data:
    rdb.table("users").insert(jobsMap).run(conn)
        .then((response)=>print('documents inserted'))
        .catchError(print);
// close the database connection:
    close();
  }


  openAndRead() {
    rdb.connect(db: "test", port:9090, host: "127.0.0.1").then((_conn) {
      conn = _conn;
      readData(conn);
    }).catchError(print);
  }
// reading documents:
  readData(conn) {
    print("test3");
    rdb.table("users").getAll("1,2,3").run(conn).then((results) {
      processJob(results);
      close();
    });
  }


// working with document data:

  processJob(results) {
    for (var row in results) {
// Refer to columns by nam:
      print('${row.id}');
      }
      }
  close() {
    conn.close();
  }
```

But in practice, the procedure does not cause a death. Although it is called  openAndRead().

catchError does not work.
 What is the easiest way to work with models and  RethinkDB?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I'd suggest using Dart's `async/await` syntax, as this makes the code easier to read.

For example

```
main() async {
  Rethinkdb rdb = new Rethinkdb();
  try {
    // get the connection
    Connection conn = await rdb.connect(port: 28015);

    // insert a row into the users table
    await rdb.table('users').insert({'a': 'b'}).run(conn);

    // query the users table
    Cursor c = await rdb.table('users').run(conn);

    // grab all the data from the cursor
    List rows = await c.toList();

    print(rows);

    // close the connection
    conn.close();
  } catch (e) {
    print('catching exception $e');
  }
}
```

You could create a class to hold the database connection, so that you don't need to keep opening and closing it.

```
class Database {
  Rethinkdb _rdb = new Rethinkdb();
  Connection _conn;

  connect(int port) async {
    _conn = await _rdb.connect(port: port);
  }

  Future<List> fetch() async {
    Cursor c = await _rdb.table('users').run(_conn);
    return await c.toList();
  }

  close() {
    _conn.close();
  }
}
```

As an aside, the driver's error handing may be broken.
The driver throws an error, when it should probably be completing the Future with an error, here:

```
}).catchError((err) => throw new RqlDriverError(
    "Could not connect to $_host:$_port.  Error $err"));
return _completer.future;
```

This may be worth a question to the package developers. You will notice that in my main() above, the exception isn't caught.

Comment: I'm using `rethinkdb` with nodejs (nestjs), your `async/await` example is what I was looking for, thank you sooooo much!!! Helped a lot